# SQL Server view metadata information

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as below:

```
create table employee_details  
(  
      id int,  
      name varchar(10)  
)
```

And this is a view based on `employee_details`:

```
create view vw_empl_details  
as  
    select id as emp_id, name as emp_name  
    from employee_details
```

I want to know which system table keeps track of column wise information for above condition..

```
id-> emp_id     
name-> emp_name
```

we have below 2 tables to keep track of tables but not sure columnwise information is available in SQL Server

```
select * from [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].[VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE]  
select * from [INFORMATION_SCHEMA].VIEW_TABLE_USAGE
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want (`sys.sql_modules.definition`):

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE OBJECT_ID = OBJECT_ID('vw_empl_details');
```

**[Rextester.com](http://rextester.com/WQNN6795)**

---

Mapping only when there is simple aliasing:

```
SELECT column_ordinal, name, source_table, source_column
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set
     ('SELECT * FROM vw_empl_details', NULL, 1);
```

Output:

[image]

**[Rextester Demo2](http://rextester.com/BXXQER82739)**

Comment: Cool...that was very quick reply!  
That's the one I was looking for..  one more question...  

If I change alias from emp_name to emp_full_name then how would I get both the rows?  
Many thanks for your help!